# Eclipse Mars.1 hangs when creating a new Oracle ADF application

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle

All is said in the title. I tried numerous solutions, in particular :

- Downloading `Oracle Enterprise Pack` for `Eclipse`;
- Downloading the latest release of `Eclipse Mars` and then adding `Oracle ADF Tools`;

The symptoms are as following :

- I choose to create a new ADF application;
- I fill in the fields of the first page of the wizard;
- When I click [Next], nothing happens but eclipse asks if I want to send an error report;
- Eclipse is frozen and i have to kill the task;

My current environment : `Windows 10 / 64 bits, jdk8u60, Version: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1), Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse 12.2.1`

My question : is there a known workaround ?

Comment: see the response at [https://community.oracle.com/message/13552632]

Answer (score 0):

This was a known bug in Mars 4.5.0.  I had the same problem and it was fixed when I updated Eclipse to Mars 4.5.1.  However, I am running Windows 7, so your mileage may vary.